# Publish app in LG Store and Samsung Store

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, webos, television, lg

Can I publish app for webOS and netcast in one Store once or I need to publish separately for webOS and netcast? And how can I publish app for Samsung smartTV and Tizen once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebOS, NetCast, Samsung SmartTV and Tizen applications all use different SDK.
In seller portals you create app and upload different binaries for different platforms, and they exist as single app.

LG seller portal (NetCast, WebOS):

http://seller.lgappstv.com/

Samsung seller portal (Samsung SmartTV, Tizen):

http://seller.samsungapps.com/

There is backward compatibility between platforms: on Samsung you can publish SmartTV app and it will work on 2015 Tizen. On LG you can publish NetCast app and it will work on WebOS 2014-2017.

However you will need to make Tizen/WebOS versions if you want to run your app on 2016 devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of webOS and netcast stores, probably others can help.

For samsung smart TV refer to 
http://samsungdforum.com/Support/Distribution

You need to 
1. Use the SDK's provided in http://samsungdforum.com/
2. Build, Test / Repackage your apps
3. Setup seller accounts with samsung TV appstore
    http://seller.samsungapps.com/tv/portal/main
4. Follow the distribution guide.

I haven't tried it myself, but it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thank's! I want to publish my app for Smart TV, and It's going to communicate with 3rd party server to get an UI. Do you know, they have any restrictions for this?

Comment: Smart TV apps are mostly web based apps. So, you need to handle issues like CORS etc. If you are planning a web based interface then using an iframe would be one option. You can do things like this. `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7xBT-UDAHX8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` Refer to [https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/?FolderName=tizen4141&FileName=index.html]